# How to get version 4.0 spring jar on maven?

Tags: spring

I searched spring on maven, and I find it at this page :http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring. The problem is I want to download 4.0 version but there is no 4.0 version in the chart.

Comment: You need this one http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core

Comment: I need spring jar includes all components jars, not only spring-core component jar. Thanks all the same.

Comment: There is no JAR which includes everything. That's the point of Maven, if you include the components which you need, Maven will download all necessary dependencies.

Comment: There are about 20 componets in spring. Do I need include them in maven pio one by one?

Comment: As of Spring 3.0 there is no more all-encompassing jar anymore. There are separate module jars en you can pick the ones you need. You need web include `spring-webmvc` which then will download all other dependencies it needs, same for jdbc, orm, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newer version of Spring can be found under group id org.springframework - [Spring 4+](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework)

There is no reason to include all features of Spring Framework in one .jar. Spring is huge and you will probably won't use every feature of Spring. Including everything will cause unnecessary overhead. Pick what components you need add them to pom.xml and Maven will download them. If you found out later you need additional dependency just add it on the fly...

As an alternative you can use Spring Boot which will generate project for you with default set up. You can generate such a project using Spring Initializr [Spring Boot Initializr](https://start.spring.io/). At the bottom click Switch to the full version. Pick what you need and hit generate project.